# plpgsql dynamic insert with tablename as variable and array variable in where clause

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

I am trying to write a function that runs an insert statement with table name as variable and the where clause accepts an array as another variable.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_dynamic_sql()
  RETURNS void
  LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS
$body$

DECLARE 
rec record;
iterator float4 := 1;
tbl_name text;

BEGIN
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS t_ar; CREATE TEMP TABLE t_ar (reg text, zones text[]);
INSERT INTO t_ar VALUES 
('NA', '{"US","UG","UC","UR"}'),
('NE', '{"UK", "SP"}'),
('LA', '{"CA","EC","WC","EC","WC"}');

FOR rec IN SELECT zones from t_ar
    LOOP 
  tbl_name := 'schema.table_' || iterator; 
  EXECUTE format('INSERT INTO %s 
          SELECT
            DATE_PART(''MONTH'', month)::INT AS month,
            SUM(COALESCE(prev_year,0))::INT AS py,
            SUM(COALESCE(last_year,0))::INT AS ly
        FROM org_table
        WHERE load_area IN (SELECT UNNEST(rec.zones))
        GROUP BY 1
        ORDER BY 1', tbl_name); 

    iterator := iterator + 1;
END LOOP;
END;
$body$
  VOLATILE
  COST 100;
```

This runs fine out of execute format but then I cannot put the table name as variable but inside execute format it shows syntax error in the SQL query. The SQL query runs alright outside.

Comment: The temporary table and the `FOR` loop seem pretty pointless. If you simplified your actual code, did you verify that the function you posted creates the error. And, most of all, **please copy and paste the complete error messages with all details, hints and context**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use placeholders and arguments in the `format()` function.

A practical tip when using `EXECUTE format()`- use `RAISE NOTICE '%',` instead of `EXECUTE` and run the function in psql to see what queries it actually generates. When you are sure that the generated queries are correct, replace `RAISE NOTICE '%',` with `EXECUTE`. Example:

```
...
FOR rec IN SELECT reg, zones FROM t_ar
LOOP 
RAISE NOTICE '%', format('
    INSERT INTO my_schema.table_%s 
    SELECT
        DATE_PART(''MONTH'', month)::INT AS month,
        SUM(COALESCE(prev_year,0))::INT AS py,
        SUM(COALESCE(last_year,0))::INT AS ly
    FROM org_table
    WHERE load_area = ANY (%L)
    GROUP BY 1
    ORDER BY 1', rec.reg, rec.zones); 
END LOOP;
...
```